# ListView not displaying text custom adapter

Tags: java, android, listview, android-adapter

Hello I am new to android development and I am trying to use a custom adapter to display some text in the listview and when I run the app on my phone it crashes...

this is my Adapter class:

```
public class EarthquakeAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Earthquake> {
    private TextView magnitude;
    private TextView location;
    private TextView date;

    public EarthquakeAdapter(@NonNull Context context, ArrayList<Earthquake> resource) {
        super(context, 0, resource);
    }

    public View getview(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Check if the existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view

        Earthquake CurrentEarthquake =  (Earthquake)getItem(position);

        View listItemView = convertView;
        if (listItemView == null) {
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        }

        magnitude = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.magnitude);
        magnitude.setText((int) CurrentEarthquake.getMagnitude());

        location = listItemView.findViewById(R.id.location);
        location.setText(CurrentEarthquake.getLocation());

        date = listItemView.findViewById(R.id.date);
        date.setText(CurrentEarthquake.getDate());

        return listItemView;
    }
}
```

and this is my logcat:

```
    01-30 23:34:38.508 11110-11110/com.example.itis.quakereportapp 
    E/System: stat file error, path is 
    /data/app/com.example.itis.quakereportapp-1/lib/arm64, exception is 
    android.system.ErrnoException: stat failed: ENOENT (No such file or 
    directory)
    01-30 23:34:38.888 11110-11134/com.example.itis.quakereportapp E/GED: 
    Failed to get GED Log Buf, err(0)

                                                                      [ 
    01-30 23:34:38.888 11110:11134 I/         ]

    elapse(include ctx switch):4357 (ms), eglInitialize
    01-30 23:34:38.890 11110-11110/com.example.itis.quakereportapp 
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

    Process: com.example.itis.quakereportapp, PID: 11110

    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0

    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1490)

    at
 android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:3060)

    at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1264)

    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:418)

    at 


 android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:371)

    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)

    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2572)

    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1956)

    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:757)

    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:822)

    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1751)

    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2326)

    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16121)

    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5185)

    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1959)

    at 
    android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1948)
                                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1724)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16121)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5185)
                                                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:639)
                                                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:574)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16121)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5185)
                                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:443)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16121)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5185)
                                                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:639)
                                                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:574)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16121)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5185)
                                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1959)
                                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1813)
                                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1722)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16121)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5185)
                                                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:639)
                                                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:574)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16121)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5185)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2532)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2226)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1323)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6686)
                                                                                     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:800)
                                                                                     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:603)
                                                                                     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:572)
                                                                                     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:786)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5834)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1119)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:885)
```

I am new to android development and I am trying to use a custom adapter to display some text in the listview and when I run the app on my phone it crashes...

Comment: You are certain that `ArrayList<Earthquake> resource` has data?

Comment: Post the LogCat.  It will tell you exactly what went wrong and where, it's very convenient.

Comment: Also this does nothing useful `View listItemView = convertView;`. If you want to rename `convertView` change the name of the parameter in your `getView()` method.

Comment: Post logcat as edit into your question if its not too long (x < 100 lines) and not as comment.

Comment: i just posted the log message... I've been trying to figure out what it is saying but can't

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is `magnitude.setText((int)CurrentEarthquake.getMagnitude());`,because `setText` can't is `Int`must be `String` so you can write this `magnitude.setText(((int)CurrentEarthquake.getMagnitude())+"");` hope help you.

Comment: The OP claims his app crashes!  I'm surprised it compiles!

Comment: Good catch, abby! @Barns [`setText(int)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(int)) exists for calling resource id strings, ie `R.string.app_name`

Comment: @Sam :: Yes, but I get a warning saying that `setText(int)` expects a "resource type of string." Anything else gets flagged and a big red line appears below the line of code. That usually isn't a good sign. But, still it will compile.

Answer (score 0):

I know this actually very stupid of me but I found the problem...

In my Adapter code is was using the method

> getview

while it is meant to be

> getView

I also learnt how the method actually works here [how getView works](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442054/how-does-arrayadapter-getview-method-works)

thank you all for your help